# Minimax Algorithm for tic tac toe in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I am trying to make the tic tac toe game in C# Windows Forms using the minimax algorithm as the opponent. So instead of making the best move, like preventing the player from winning or playing a move that allows it to get closer to winning, it moves to the following empty index on the board. So how could I fix the algorithm?

```
int evaluate(int[] grid)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3)
        {
            if (grid[i] == 0) continue;

            if (grid[i] == grid[i + 1] && grid  [i] == grid[i + 2])
                return grid[i]==1 ? 10 :-10;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (grid[i] == 0) continue;

            if (grid[i] == grid[i + 3] && grid[i] == grid[i + 6])
                return grid[i] == 1 ? 10 : -10;
        }

        if ((grid[0] == grid[4] && grid[4] == grid[8]) || (grid[2] == grid[4] && grid[4] == grid[6]))
            return grid[4] == 1 ? 10 : -10;

        return 0;
    }

    bool isMovesLeft(int[] grid)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< grid.Length; i++)
        {
            if (grid[i] == 0) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    int miniMax(int[] grid,int depth, bool isMax) 
    {
        int isWon = evaluate(grid);

        if (isWon == 10 || isWon == -10)
            return isWon;

        if(!isMovesLeft(grid))
            return 0;

        if (isMax)
        {
            int best = int.MinValue;

            for(int i = 0;i< grid.Length;i++)
            {
                if (grid[i] == 0)
                {
                    grid[i] = 1;

                    best = Math.Max(best,miniMax(grid, depth+1, !isMax));

                    grid[i] = 0;
                }
            }

            return best;
        }
        else
        {
            int best = int.MaxValue;

            for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
            {
                if (grid[i] == 0)
                {
                    grid[i] = 2;

                    best = Math.Min(best, miniMax(grid, depth+1, !isMax));

                    grid[i] = 0;
                }
            }

            return best;
        }
    }

    void moveByAI()
    {
        int best = int.MinValue;
        int move = -1;

        for(int i =0; i<9;i++)
        {
            if (grids[i]==0)
            {
                grids[i] = 2;

                int locValue = miniMax(grids, 0, true);

                grids[i] = 0;

                if(locValue > best)
                {
                    move = i;
                    best = locValue;
                    MessageBox.Show(""+i);
                }
            }
        }
        
        buttons[move].PerformClick();
}
```

Comment: It looks like 2 is the AI with 1 being the human player. With 2 winning, the score becomes -10, so your `moveByAI` loop should be looking for the move that yields the smallest score, not the largest.

Comment: I changed int best = int.MaxValue and  (locValue> best) to locValue<best, the problem still exist, consistently when I play the corners move

Comment: In the `evaluate` function, you check `grid[i] != 0` when looking at rows and columns. But you forgot to do that for diagonals.

Comment: wow thanks, it is working properly knows, I kept looking at the wrong place